# Python: Составить список и преобразовать его в словарь, удалить запись о студенте организовав поиск по номеру

Tags: python, list, dict

Составить список данных 7 студентов, представленный в виде:

```
[[№, ФИО, Возраст, Группа, Число сданных экзаменов], [№, ФИО, Возраст, 
Группа, Число сданных экзаменов], [№, ФИО, Возраст, Группа, Число сданных 
экзаменов]…]
```

Преобразовать список в словарь вида:

```
{№: [ФИО, Возраст, Группа, Число сданных экзаменов], №: [....], №: [....]…}
```

Как составить и преобразовать списки в словарь и после удалить запись о студенте,  организовав поиск по номеру студента?

Первый код не увенчался успехом, выбивает ошибку

```
s = {1: ['Ковалев', '19', 'МК', '4'], 2: ['Светова В.М','18', 'ИС', '5'], 3: ['Мирцова С.К.', '18', 'ИС', '5'], 4: ['Гримов Н.Ю', '19', 'ФК', '6'], 5: ['Снегирев С.Ф', '18', 'МК', '3'], 6: ['Романов М.Г', '23', 'ФК', '6'], 7: ['Ломова И.Р', '20', 'МС', '6']}
num= input("Введите номер студента: ")
key = num
flag = True

for search_ss in s:
    if s[search_ss]['key'] == num:
        print(s[search_ss])
        
        flag = False

if flag:
    print('Искомое значение отсутствует')
```

Во втором коде "застрял" и не знаю как продолжать чтобы добиться решения

```
s = [('1'), ('2'), ('3'), ('4'), ('5'), ('6'), ('7')]
s1 = [['Ковалев, 19, ГС, 6'], ['Снегирева, 21, МК, 6'], ['Щученко, 24, ФК, 6'], ['Краснова, 18, МП, 4'], ['Звенева, 21, МП, 5'], ['Кириленко, 20, ГК, 6'], ['Ковалева, 19, ГС, 4']]
stud = dict(zip(s, s1))
print(stud)
```

Comment: как вы пытались решить данный вопрос? правила говорят что если вы просите чтобы вам помогли решить школьную задачу покажите ваши варианты её решения

Comment: Список составлять по средством input? или как?

Comment: Список можно составить вручную, или воспользоваться списками из второй попытки, у меня по крайней мере на них не ругался питон

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ваш массив с данными

```
s = [('1'), ('2'), ('3'), ('4'), ('5'), ('6'), ('7')]
    s1 = [['Ковалев, 19, ГС, 6'], ['Снегирева, 21, МК, 6'], ['Щученко, 24, ФК, 6'], ['Краснова, 18, МП, 4'], ['Звенева, 21, МП, 5'], ['Кириленко, 20, ГК, 6'], ['Ковалева, 19, ГС, 4']]
    stud = dict(zip(s, s1))
```

Создаём переменную поиска:

```
num = str(input("Введите номер студента: "))

print(stud[num])
```

Удаляем найденное значениеЖ

```
del stud[num]
```

Если вывести опять словарь увидим что элемента уже нетЖ

```
print(stud)
```

Полный код: ))

```
s = [('1'), ('2'), ('3'), ('4'), ('5'), ('6'), ('7')]
s1 = [['Ковалев, 19, ГС, 6'], ['Снегирева, 21, МК, 6'], ['Щученко, 24, ФК, 6'], ['Краснова, 18, МП, 4'], ['Звенева, 21, МП, 5'], ['Кириленко, 20, ГК, 6'], ['Ковалева, 19, ГС, 4']]
stud = dict(zip(s, s1))


num = str(input("Введите номер студента: "))

print(stud[num])
del stud[num]

print(stud)
```